# Processing multiple files in Python, and matching on fields

Tags: python, file, pattern-matching

I have a number of CSV files which I need to compare to one 'Master List', and determine, based on a unique ID, if these other files contain entries for that key.

What would the easiest way to do this in Python be? I.e what kind of structures would you suggest I read the data into, and how would you suggest I iterate through it?

Here is an example of the data and output I am looking for.

```
**Master List**

Unique ID : File Name : File Version : Responsible Party

J578221 : Expander : 1.23 : Joe Bloggs

KK89821 : Top : 0.9 : Mike Smith


**Location X**

Region : File Name : Unique ID

USA : Acme Expander : J578221

USA : Acme Tail : MK33431

**Location Z**

Reqion : File Name : Unique ID : Date Added

China : Expander : J578221 : 03-04-2012

HK : Acme Top : KK89821 : 06-07-2012

**Output:**

Unique ID : File Name : File Version : Responsible Party : In Location X : In Location Z

J578221 : Expander : 1.23 : Joe Bloggs : YES : YES

KK89821 : Top : 0.9 : Mike Smith : NO : YES
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ? What problem arose ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be using regular expressions ([see documentation here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)) to retrieve the key of each line in the master file. (You might need to evaluate the structure of the files first and modify your expression if the position of the Unique-ID changes.)

Store this ID List in a dictionary as key and use a list as a value, indicating the files in which each of the master keys is included.

You could afterwards filter the dictionary for IDs (Keys) for one or multiple files or look up the files containing one particular ID.

Comment: I ended up reading the keys of the master list into a dictionary, with the ID as the key and the list as its value (as suggested my michael), and read the other two files into dictionaries in the same way. Then iterated through the master list dictionary, doing something like:

if id in sorted(masterdict):
    if id in locationxdict and id in locationzdict:
        ...process...